# emulate xbox 360/one using a HID device

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, xbox360

I'm trying to emulate a xbox 360/one controller using a HID device that is already connected to the PC.
I can read data from it and I will have to map it to the XInput structure.
Is there another way to do this without building a virtual driver to simulate a game-pad and using a feeder to send in the input from my own HID device?

Development is done using Qt5.4 and C++.